# HTML relative path in osX

Tags: html, macos, path, relative-path

So I'm trying to put a link with relative path in my index.html page.

The full path, copied directly from file info is "/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/AMMProject/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAmm/web/M1". The file is called "descrizione.html".

I've put as base-path this:

```
<base href="Users/xxxxx/Desktop/AMMProject/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAmm/">
```

and when referencing to the page:

```
<a href="web/M1/descrizione.html">Description page.</a>
```

this will give a 404 error when trying to access the link.

Using osX latest version and html5

Answer (score 0):

the `base` element should be in `header`. Also, the path should be most likely prefixed with `/` (so that it gives an absolute path), i.e.,

```
<base href="/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/AMMProject/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAmm/">
```

Comment: this ain't working. I've put the base in <head> with the / as prefix and still not working. The problem is not related to the base, but to the link itself. for example if I put a normal

    <a href="Users/xxxxx/Desktop/AMMProject/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAMM/ProgettoAmm/web/M1/descrizione.html">Description page.</a>    

it will give the same 404 error.

Comment: @kHz- ah, 404 error, so you are serving the website via a local webserver?

Comment: if yes, then you most likely don't need the base at all - if `index.html` is in the root folder (of the website) and `web` is a subfolder, then direct `href` with `web/M1/descrizione.html` should work...